# How to use SaveFileDialog with Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am studying Blazor Server app development and would like to create a function to download database tables as CSV files.
Specifically, I want to be able to select the save destination like SaveFileDialog.

The database used in my environment is PostgreSQL, and I used NpgSQL to download it as follows.

```
<button type="button" @onclick="@CsvTest">
    CSV Download
</button>


@code {

public void CsvTest()
{
    string conStr = "Host=localhost;Database=SQLbeginner;Username=postgres;Password=****";
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conStr);
    conn.Open();
    using (var reader = conn.BeginTextExport("COPY  (SELECT * FROM test_table ORDER BY id) TO STDOUT WITH CSV"))
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"table_export.csv", reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

}

I want to create a feature like SaveFileDialog, but I don't know how to implement it without looking for a similar example.

I would like advice on implementing this feature.
Sorry for the rudimentary question.

Answer (score 0):

It was very rudimentary.
I succeeded when I enabled the setting to check the save location in the download settings of the browser.